# Is logback better than log4j2

Tags: logback

i have been playing around with log4j2 with a custom logger on top of it. Unfortunately, the solution was rejected by my architects with the reason that logback is better than log4j2, specifically because of the recommendation coming from logback team.

Can the logback team provide any proof or reasoning for the statement that logback is better than log4j2?

Comment: This question is not appropriate for SO. I would close it if I were not involved in the topic. See  http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

log4j2 is better on many aspects as per the comparisons